# IOS/Objective-C/Storyboard: Gesture Recognizer Accessible to Whole App with Tabbar Possible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitabbarcontroller, gesture, uiswipegesturerecognizer

I would like to create a gesture recognizer that would be available across an entire app to give users access to a shortcut/help menu wherever they are.  However, as the app has many screens, I don't want to have to create a separate gesture recognizer in every one.

I thought of using the tabbarcontroller which is available, however, touching anywhere on it seems to represent a tap on the tab bar buttons.

Is it possible to put an upward swipe gesture recognizer on a tab bar that can be distinguished from a tap on a button?  How would I get it to distinguish between the two actions? Some modification of the following?

```
-(void)createUpwardSwipeTabBAr {
    UISwipeGestureRecognizer *upGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleHelp:)];
    leftFilter.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionUp;
    [leftFilter setNumberOfTouchesRequired:1];
    leftFilter.delegate = self;
    [_tabBarController addGestureRecognizer:upwardSwipe];

}

-(void)handleHelp:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
[self launchHelpVC];
}
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Comment: Create a base UIViewController and subclass it with all view controllers.

Comment: I do have a base UIViewController class that  all the other VC classes subclass where I could put code.  However, what element would I attach the recognizer to?   I thought of using the UITabBarController as it is a visible element common to all of them.

Comment: Attach it to self.view.

Answer (score 0):

I have a simple idea. It could work.

Edit the class where you want to handle swipe and join the gesture recognizer to the root view.

```
{
  guard let parentView = UIApplication.shared.windows.first else {return}
  // create the recognizer and attach it
  UISwipeGestureRecognizer *upGesture = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleHelp:)];
  ...
  parentView.addGestureRecognizer(upwardSwipe)
}

- (void)handleHelp:(UIGestureRecognizer*)recognizer {
   [self launchHelpVC];
}
```

I mixed swift and ObjC but it is simple. UIWindow is derived from UIView so it should handle all gestures that are not handled and passed to next view in hierarchy.

Another, maybe better approach is to add gesture recognizer to tabBar instead of _tabBarController.
Use `_tabBarController.tabBar`.